# WITH returned table behave unexpectedly when used with RETURNING in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm stumped. Why does this work fine...

```
WITH sst AS (SELECT * FROM subtopics_results WHERE student_id = 2)
SELECT * FROM subtopics_results AS str 
WHERE (subtopic_id,student_id) IN (SELECT subtopic_id,student_id FROM sst);
```

But the below doesn't - it returns an empty table. I can query the returned table `sst` just fine (e.g. `SELECT * FROM sst`), but when I try to use

```
WITH sst AS (
    -- inside block is working fine
    INSERT INTO subtopics_results (paper_id, student_id, subtopic_id, marks_scored) 
        (
            WITH subtopics AS (
            SELECT qbr.question_id, q.subtopic_id, qbr.student_id, q.paper_id, qbr.marks_scored
            FROM question AS q
            JOIN question_breakdown_result AS qbr
            ON qbr.question_id = q.question_id
            WHERE paper_id = 1 AND qbr.student_id = 2
            )
            SELECT paper_id, student_id, subtopic_id, SUM(marks_scored)
            FROM subtopics GROUP BY subtopic_id, student_id, paper_id
            HAVING SUM(marks_scored) > 2
        ) 
    RETURNING subtopic_id, student_id
) 
-- this returns an empty table, even though identical to the above.
SELECT * FROM subtopics_results AS str 
WHERE (subtopic_id,student_id) IN (SELECT subtopic_id,student_id FROM sst);
```

I'm trying to select all the pairs in the table `subtopics_results` (`subtopic_id` and `student_id`) after an insertion, but keep getting nothing back, even though I do expect to have results.

I have tried inner joins, no avail.

Is this to do with the `RETURNING` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is documented in ["7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in `WITH`"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> (...)
>
> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each
>   other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates
>   actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with
>   the same snapshot (see [Chapter
>   13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they
>   cannot "see" one another's effects on the target tables. (...)
>
> (...)

Maybe using `UNION ALL` to merge the rows returned by `RETURNING` and the ones already in the table **before** the `INSERT` happens can do what you want here.

```
WITH
sst AS
(
INSERT INTO subtopics_results
            (...)
       RETURNING *
)
SELECT sst.*
       FROM sst
UNION ALL
SELECT str.*
       FROM subtopics_results AS str 
       WHERE (str.subtopic_id,
              str.student_id) IN (SELECT sst.subtopic_id,
                                         sst.student_id
                                         FROM sst);
```

Or, if you just want the inserted rows back (that's not entirely clear to me) simply use:

```
INSERT INTO subtopics_results
            (...)
       RETURNING *;
```

Comment: works great! thanks @stickybit. I had a feeling it was to do with the execution order.. To clarify - the `select` before the `union all` returns the inserted rows, and the `select` after it returns the rows that do already exist, correct? But wouldn't the second `select` statement (after the `union all`) also be executed concurrently, since it too is dependent on the `sst` table? Why does this one work fine?

Comment: @lionbigcat: Yes, the first gets the inserted rows and the second those already in the table **before** the statement is received. So it doesn't see any of the modifications too, but that doesn't matter because it gets the state **before** the modifications happen.